# Good way to flush scanf buffer when invalid entry entered

Tags: c, gcc, scanf

I have been thinking of ways to flush bad entries in `scanf` functions to allow for loop prompts to do their job.

I have a function call here that flushes the input. This works but it's still buggy if I enter something like `2q` when I ask for an `int`.

```
void flushKeyBoard()
{
    int ch; //variable to read data into
    while((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}
```

And then I'll have something like this in another function:

```
printf("Enter a value: ");
check = scanf("%f", &b);

while(check == 0)
{
    printf("Invalid number entered. Please re-enter: ");
    check = scanf("%f, &b");
    flushKeyBoard();
}
```

Any better ideas? Someone suggested fflush(); but it's not really standard to use that here..

Comment: Read C-faq question [12.26a](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html) and [12.26b](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html).

Comment: Your existing `flushKeyBoard` looks good, what problem are you having exactly?

Comment: Whether you want to consider "2q" as a valid int and discard the "q" , or if you want to discard the whole line, is something that you have to  control in the piece of code that is doing the `scanf`. If you want to consider "2q" to be a mistake (as opposed to reading "2" then discarding the q) You could update `flushKeyboard` to return `bool` to indicate whether or not it actually cleared something.

Comment: scanf() can return EOF, along with 0 or 1.   Any other value (in the posted code) besides 1 is an error.   so code should be checking for an EOF, perhaps after the while loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Using `getchar` (common, easily comprehensible)

```
int c;

while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'); /* <note the semicolon! */

if (c == EOF) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        /* Handle stdin EOF. */
    }
    else {
        /* Handle stdin error. */
    }
}
```

---

## Using `fgets` (less common, less comprehensible)

```
char buf[8];

while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) != NULL) {
    size_t len = strlen(buf);

    /*
     * Exit the loop if either EOF was encountered before '\n', or
     * if '\n' is detected.
     */
    if (len + 1 != sizeof(buf) || memchr(buf, '\n', len))
        break;
}
    
if (feof(stdin)) {
    /* Handle stdin EOF. */
}
else {
    /* Handle stdin error. */
}
```

---

## Using a scanset with `scanf` (likely uncommon, easily comprehensible)

```
/*
 * Combining the scanset with assignment suppression (the '*' before the
 * scanset) will return EOF on EOF/error and 0 if '\n' was read.
 */
if (scanf("%*[^\n]") == EOF) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        // Handle stdin EOF.
    }
    else {
        // Handle stdin error.
    }
}
getchar(); // Flush the '\n'.
```

---

## Using `getline` (likely uncommon, difficult)

```
char *buf = NULL;
size_t bufsize = 0;
ssize_t len;

/* getline() will stop reading on '\n' or EOF. */
len = getline(&buf, &bufsize, stdin);

/* No bytes read and EOF encountered, or there was an error. */
if (len == -1) {
    if (feof(stdin)) {
        /* Handle stdin EOF. */
    }
    else if (ferror(stdin)) {
        /* Handle stdin error. */
    }
    else {
        /* Handle errno error, if desired. */
    }
    /*
     * The value of "buf" is indeterminate here, so you likely
     * just want to return from the function/program at this point
     * rather than continuing and potentially freeing an invalid
     * buffer.
     */
}
free(buf);
```

---

Of course, all of these methods assume you want to handle things that happen on EOF/error differently than with `\n`, perhaps even all three being separate cases. For example, by placing one of the above snippets into a self-contained function, you might return `0` if `\n` was read or `EOF` on EOF/error, or even `0` on `\n`, `EOF` on EOF, and `1` on error.

Things worth noting:

- The `getchar` and `fgets` methods are 100% cross-platform. I prefer the `getchar` method for its simplicity.
- The scanset method is less cross-platform only because not all compilers implement scansets (and are therefore not C99-compliant).
- The `getline` method is also not quite cross-platform: it's primarily implemented on GNU/Linux and on some other POSIX operating systems; this does not include Windows at this time. It isn't terribly difficult to write one yourself once you have some experience managing memory and working with pointers, but you'd be better off using one of the first two methods since writing an implementation of `getline` would likely end up using `fgetc` or `fgets` anyway (`fgetc(stdin)` and `getchar()` should behave identically).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
fscanf(stdin, "%*[^\n]%*c");
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways of doing this.  Effectively, what you're trying to do is consume a line of text up to a \n character (or an EOF.)  To do this properly, you should use sscanf (or fscanf.)

```
sscanf("%*[^\n]\n");
```

This uses the regular expression [^\n]*\n  (Any number of characters that are NOT \n, followed by a \n) and consumes everything matching that.

Edit: Because I'm dumb and forgot that scanf regex's use a slightly different syntax.